# Show $Q_1 \cap Q_2 $ is $\cong$ to the elliptic curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\lambda$ be an arbitrary constant and consider the two quadric surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ given by $Q_1 = V(wx - yz)$ and $Q_2 = V(wy - (x-z)(x-\lambda z)).$

Prove that $Q_1 \cap Q_2 $ is isomorphic to the elliptic curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ defined by $E = V(y^2z - x(x-z)(x-\lambda z)).$

attempt: $f: Q_1 \cap Q_2 \rightarrow  E $
defined by 
$f[x:y:z:w] = [x:y:z]$  (assuming $(x,y,z)$ is not equal to $(0,0,0)$
and 
$f[0:0:0:1] = [0:0:1]$

and similarly define $g: E \rightarrow Q_1 \cap Q_2$ by 
$g[x:y:z] = [x:y:z:yz/x]$
and set
$g[0:1:0] = [0:1:0:0]$ and 
$g[0:0:1] =  [0:0:0:1] $.

I have also a hint as:

start with a map

$[w,x,y,z]\mapsto[x,y,z]$,

defined whenever $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$. By constructing local inverses, we may be able to prove that this is an isomorphism of open sets:

$(Q_1\cap Q_2)\setminus [1,0,0,0]\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} E\setminus[0,0,1]$.

Next, we need to extend the map to the point $[1,0,0,0]$. Since you know the image needs to be $[0,0,1]$, you might try writing

$[x,y,z]=\left[\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z},1\right]$,

then try to use the equations of the quadric surfaces to rewrite the right-hand side in a way that it is well-defined at $[1,0,0,0]$.

I am stuck. Can someone please help me? I would really appreciate.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea!

To define $f$ at $[1:0:0:0]$, you can indeed write $f([w:x:y:z]) = [x/z : y/z : 1]$, and then use the equations of the quadrics to turn this into something regular at $[1:0:0:0]$.

The first quadric gives you
$$ x/z = y/w.$$
which is regular at $[1:0:0:0]$, since $w$ is non-vanishing there.

The second quadric gives you
$$ y/z = x^2/wz - (1 + \lambda) x/w + \lambda z/w .$$
The second and third terms are already regular at $[1:0:0:0]$, but the first term is not. However, using the first quadric once more, we get
$$ y/z = xy/w^2 - (1 + \lambda) x/w + \lambda z/w,$$
which is now regular at $[1:0:0:0]$.

Similarly, to define your map $g$ at $[0:1:0]$ and $[0:0:1]$ you could rewrite $yz/x$ using the equation of the elliptic curve, then clear the denominators:
$$ g([x:y:z]) = [yz/x:x:y:z] = [(x-z)(x-\lambda z)/y:x:y:z:]=[(x-z)(x-\lambda z):xy:y^2:yz].$$

I'll leave you to finish off.

Comment: I'm using the same notation as you: $f$ goes from the intersection of quadrics to the elliptic curve. $g$ goes the other way: from the elliptic curve to the intersection of quadrics. (i) You should explicitly check that the image of $f$ really is contained inside the elliptic curve, and the image of $g$ really is contained inside the intersection of quadrics. (ii) You should check that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are the identity maps.

Comment: (iii) Finally, you should check that $f$ and $g$ are regular, by checking that, around every point, there exists an open neighbourhood on which $f$ or $g$ can be expressed in terms of regular functions. But that's exactly what I've done in my answer.

Comment: so after we have shown that $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other, then we can conclude it's an isomorphism ? since you have that $f,g$ are regular already.

Comment: Yes - provided that you've checked that the image of $f$ really lies inside the elliptic curve and the image of $g$ really lies inside the intersection of quadrics. That isn't too difficult.

Comment: No, showing the image of $f$ really lies inside the elliptic curve means checking that, if $[w:x:y:z]$ obeys $wx = yz$ and $wy-(x-z)(x-\lambda z) = 0$, then $[X:Y:Z]=f([w:x:y:z])$ obeys $Y^2 Z - X(X-Z)(X-\lambda Z) = 0$.

Comment: by obey, you mean if $[w:x:y:z]$ it makes sense using the intersection and showing this point makes sense in the elliptic curve?

Comment: I mean that if $[w:x:y:z]$ lies on the intersection of quadrics then $f([w:x:y:z]) $ lies on the elliptic curve

Comment: Ok . I will work it out hopefully . Thanks